# How to analyze same set of modules in Sonar

Tags: maven, sonarqube5.1

I am using Sonar 5.1. My projects is divided in to multiple releases R1, R2...and so on. All releases have same set of modules with some changes. I want to run the sonar report for all the releases using Maven in the same Sonar to show the report in one dashboard. After running Sonar for the first release when I am running sonar on the second release, I am getting error: "...module is already part of project xyz...". I tried using different parameters like projectName and projectKey (mvn sonar:sonar -DprojectName="R1") but it didn't help. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an incremental release like any other java maven application.

Make sure parent key is consistent. So now when you run second analysis first analysis sources will b overwritten without complications... You can see old release metrics using compare or any other history widgets.

**In maven-sonar key is formed as a concatenation of group and project id like -**

```
GroupID:ArtifactID
```

sample: com.example:myapp

It seems you are changing *key* of only parent pom and trying to analysis. You have to change key in every pom. But, bcoz it is incremental analysis lets not change artifact or group id